# Exception when using printf(

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write a program that takes user input and uses it to print out a payroll statement. However, this is displayed after all user input is inputed, I get an exception. It prompts for user input, and as soon as I press enter after the last input required, the program gets the exception above. Can someone explain what is wrong with the code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // prompt user input of payroll info
    System.out.print("Enter employee’s name: ");
    String name = input.next(); 
    System.out.print("Enter number of hours worked in a week: ");
    double hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter hourly pay rate: ");
    double hourlyPayRate = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter federal tax withholding rate: ");
    double federalTaxRate = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter state tax withholding rate: ");
    double stateTaxRate = input.nextDouble();

    // display results
    double grossPay, federal, state, totalDeduction;
    System.out.printf(
            "Employee Name: " + name + 
            "\nHours Worked: " + hoursWorked +
            "\nPay Rate: $" + hourlyPayRate +
            "\nGross Pay: $" + (grossPay = hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate) +
            "\nDeductions:\n   Federal Witholding (20.0%): $" +
            (federal = grossPay * federalTaxRate) +
            "\n   State Witholding (9.0%): $" + (state = grossPay stateTaxRate) +
            "\n   Total Deduction: $" + (totalDeduction = federal + state) +
            "\nNet Pay: $" + (grossPay - totalDeduction));
}}
```

The program runs, prompts user input, and then displays:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException:                  Conversion = ')'
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2579)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2565)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at payroll.Payroll.main(Payroll.java:34)
```

C:\Users\thril\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)

Comment: Solution: don't use printf if you don't need it. I think the `%` is messing with printf, escape it with `%%`.

Comment: `%` is a special character in printf. If you want to print a literal percent sign, you need to escape it by printing two: `%%`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax